# Android IPV6 problem, wifi instability/disconnection

Tags: wi-fi, ipv6

My lg g4 has wifi instability/random wifi disconnection when using ipv6 with wifi.

The only workaround I have found is to disable IPV6 on my phone.

I have already tried reseting/updating the phone without sucess

Is there anything I could do to keep IPV6 (I have heard it's not a very good thing to disable it)
? Maybe change some router setting ?

Comment: This is very hard to answer without more data. What kind of Wi-Fi access points and router do you have, and what are the current settings?

Comment: If you need more excuses: http://ipv6bingo.com/